# How this "Quine" code work in detail?

Tags: html, css

Source: [Rosettacode Quine for HTML/CSS](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quine) (find the HTML/CSS section).

The following code, when saved as an html file, rendered in browser as its source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML/CSS Quine</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    * { font: 10pt monospace; }

    head, style { display: block; }
    style { white-space: pre; }

    style:before {
        content:
        "\3C""!DOCTYPE html\3E"
        "\A\3Chtml\3E\A"
        "\3Chead\3E\A"
        "\9\3Ctitle\3E""HTML/CSS Quine""\3C/title\3E\A"
        "\9\3Cstyle type=\22text/css\22\3E";
    }
    style:after {
        content:
        "\3C/style\3E\A"
        "\3C/head\3E\A"
        "\3C""body\3E\3C/body\3E\A"
        "\3C/html\3E";
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I don't know how this works, and the citing page didn't explain at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "cheaty" quine in the sense that it essentially introspects its own source code, and styles it to make it visible rather than the default invisible.  The CSS rules are best explained one-by-one:

---

```css
* { font: 10pt monospace; }
```

This is just for aesthetics, since code tends to be marked up in monospace.

```css
head, style { display: block; }
```

Normally, content in `<head>` and `<style>` is invisible.  I don't know if styling these elements like this is strictly standards-conformant, but in general I think the spec gives a lot of freedom to document authors when it comes to changing the `display` of elements to something else. For instance, you can style inline or block elements as tables, table-rows and table-cells without problem.  We want to make these elements visible in order to make the CSS source code render.

```css
style { white-space: pre; }
```

This is again for aesthetics: this makes whitespace inside the script element render verbatim, rather than applying the usual coalescing rule for HTML elements where runs of whitespace get replaced by a single space.

```css
style:before {
    content:
    "\3C""!DOCTYPE html\3E"
    "\A\3Chtml\3E\A"
    "\3Chead\3E\A"
    "\9\3Ctitle\3E""HTML/CSS Quine""\3C/title\3E\A"
    "\9\3Cstyle type=\22text/css\22\3E";
}
style:after {
    content:
    "\3C/style\3E\A"
    "\3C/head\3E\A"
    "\3C""body\3E\3C/body\3E\A"
    "\3C/html\3E";
}
```

These rules insert the required HTML code before and after the `<style>` element, since we can't render these via CSS only.  In CSS, a backslash followed by runs of hexadecimal digits forms an escape sequence—`\3C` and `\3E` are `<` and `>` respectively, `\A` denotes newline and `\9` denotes tab.  Multiple strings given in a row (with optional whitespace between them) are concatenated together.